# Swift: Why no elements are adding to my array while using append?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to create a Fibonacci Sequence. A user will enter a number, For example, 9 then the Fibonacci Sequence will be displayed, ending with the nearest Fibonacci Sequence number. So, in this case: 0,1,1,2,3,5,8

I am having a problem with storing elements in the 2D array. When loop starts from 0, 0 at 0 index is stored, and when loop comes to 1, then again 1 at index 0 is stored, but it should have stored at index 1. This is causing index out of range error in the upper part of code. Should I use something different than append or something else?

```
 func fabino(until: Int) {

    if until > 2 {
        for number in 0...until {

            var arrayOfDemoNumbers = [Int]()

            if number > 1 {
               arrayOfDemoNumbers.append(arrayOfDemoNumbers[number - 1] + arrayOfDemoNumbers[number - 2])
                listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers + "\(arrayOfDemoNumbers[number]), "
            }else{
                sum = number + sum
                arrayOfDemoNumbers.append(sum)
               // arrayOfDemoNumbers[number] = sum
                listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers + "\(sum), "
                dump(arrayOfDemoNumbers)
            }
        }}else{
            self.listOfNumbers = "0,1,1"
        }

        labelToChange.text = listOfNumbers

    }
```

Comment: you are initializing an empty arrayOfDemoNumbers every time it loops thus clearing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 func fabino(until: Int) {
    var arrayOfDemoNumbers = [Int]()

    if until > 2 {
        for number in 0...until {

            if number > 1 {
               arrayOfDemoNumbers.append(arrayOfDemoNumbers[number - 1] + arrayOfDemoNumbers[number - 2])
                listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers + "\(arrayOfDemoNumbers[number]), "
            }else{
                sum = number + sum
                arrayOfDemoNumbers.append(sum)
               // arrayOfDemoNumbers[number] = sum
                listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers + "\(sum), "
                dump(arrayOfDemoNumbers)
            }
        }}else{
            self.listOfNumbers = "0,1,1"
        }

        labelToChange.text = listOfNumbers

    }
```

Comment: Good answers explain what the issue was and how the answer fixes it. Please don't just post code.